# Python: Importing an instance of a class but receiving bytecode

Tags: python, import, bytecode

I am currently working on a standalone module which runs a function to pick up the instance of a class created in another module and store it within a tuple. When I run the code it works but it is returning bytecode, 
(, )
This leads me to believe it is being imported correctly, however not in the format I would like. Any way to translate this within the current module or am I importing it wrong?

Comment: .pyc files are bytecode, and .py files are readable Python code files, so make sure you're not importing a pyc

Comment: Please provide examples and output if possible. Which python version are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify "returning bytecode, (,)"?. Are you saying that the function returns an empty tuple or that quite literally, you are getting some sort of a reference to the python bytecode? Can you print the type of the result? You have little chance of getting this question answers with such skimpy information. An example showing the issue should be added.

Comment: @JosephJames I don't see how that makes a difference. If I import a module, python will choose to import the `.py` or the `.pyc` depending which is newer. Under normal circumstances we don't choose or care which one python gets.